# finding projects based on users in basecamp3 replica

Tags: oauth-2.0

I attempted to display projects depending on users but was unable to do so in Basecamp3 using htnl css js node.

I attempted acquiring the authorised users in Basecamp 3, but I didn't get it, and I need to display the projects based on users.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.